# Using Table to make a set of replacement rules for functions

Tags: matrix, function-construction, replacement, list-manipulation

I have a 3x3 matrix of functions.  It looks like

```
k1[xx_]:={
  {k1[1,1][xx],k1[1,2][xx],k1[1,3][xx]},
  {k1[1,2][xx],k1[2,2][xx],k1[2,3][xx]},
  {k1[1,3][xx],k1[2,3][xx],k1[3,3][xx]}
}
```

(It's symmetric on the first two arguments.) I want to replace all of the `k1[i,j]` functions with different functions.  What I want to do is, basically

```
Flatten[Table[
  k1[a, b] -> (1/c^4 k1c4[a, b][#] &), {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}]]
```

or with slightly different syntax

```
  Flatten[Table[
   k1[a, b] -> Function[xx,1/c^4 k1c4[a, b][xx]], {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}]]
```

Neither of these work.  Instead of a matrix

```
{
  {k1c4[1,1][xx],k1c4[1,2][xx],k1c4[1,3][xx]},
  {k1c4[1,2][xx],k1c4[2,2][xx],k1c4[2,3][xx]},
  {k1c4[1,3][xx],k1c4[2,3][xx],k1c4[3,3][xx]}
}
```

I get a matrix

```
{
  {k1c4[a,b][xx],k1c4[a,b][xx],k1c4[a,b][xx]},
  {k1c4[a,b][xx],k1c4[a,b][xx],k1c4[a,b][xx]},
  {k1c4[a,b][xx],k1c4[a,b][xx],k1c4[a,b][xx]}
}
```

which is meaningless because `a` and `b` aren't defined anywhere.

How can I make the  replacement list I want using something like `Table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SetAttributes[k1, Orderless]; 
kk1[xx_] := Array[k1[##][xx] &, {3, 3}]
kk1[xx]
```

> {{k1[1, 1][xx], k1[1, 2][xx], k1[1, 3][xx]},
>     {k1[1, 2][xx], k1[2, 2][xx], k1[2, 3][xx]},
>   {k1[1, 3][xx], k1[2, 3][xx], k1[3, 3][xx]}}

You can use `With` in the first argument of `Table` to inject values of the iterator variables `a` and `b` into the rule elements:

```
rules = Flatten[ Table[With[{a = a, b = b}, k1[a, b] -> (1/c^4 k1c4[a, b][#] &)], 
 {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}]];

kk1[[x]] /. rules
```

[image]

A simpler alternative is to use `Pattern`s to define the replacement rule:

```
rule = k1[a__][xx] :>  k1c4[a][xx] / c^4;
kk1[xx] /. rule
```

> same result